# Perform a command on all files in a directory with Node.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

How can one with node.js perform a custom command on all files in a directory, e.g: compress all media files into a given subdirectory? (ffmpeg is set up and works correctly)

This does not work for me:

`foreach -g "/.mp4" --no-c -x "ffmpeg -y -i #{path}.mp4  -r 15 -s 480x320 -ac 1 -c:a copy ./compacted/#{name}___compacted.mp4"`

I think there might be something wrong with the spaces and the periods in the filenames, but could not figure out how to solve this.

Comment: What language are you actually trying to use? That's not something that would run in nodejs, and I don't recall bash having a foreach - is that csh? Maybe you could provide a description of what happens when you run that?

Comment: I try to use the foreach-cli [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreach-cli to run the bash command within the last pair double-quotes

Comment: Interesting. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { foreach -g "/.mp4" --no-c -x "ffmpeg -y -i #{path}.mp4  -r 15 -s 480x320 -ac 1 -c:a copy ./compacted/#{name}___compacted.mp4"
                                                                         ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
...    
the unexpected string is pointed as: "/.mp4"

Comment: Hmm. maybe bad glob? Have you tried `"*.mp4"`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same result...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159398/discussion-between-will-and-janos).